# Vertically align image formatted as table cell to text formated as table cell

Tags: html, css

In my mobile theme I have been playing around with the CSS of my tables to make the information clearer and easier to understand for my users.

In column 1 I have a network logo, in column 2 I have text which I have formatted both as (display:table-cell) and given them a border of 1px.

The problem is I can't get them to vertically align exactly I have attached an image to show you exactly what I mean.

http://pasteboard.co/1vII00Yg.png

[image]

As its an image in column one when I first inserted it in there it was messed up so I did this in the CSS to try to align it to the adjacent text cells.

HTML

```
<td class="network-cell">
 <center><img alt="EE" src="/wp-content/themes/wootique-child/images/network-logos/ee-logo.png" class="network-logo"></center>                      
</td>
```

CSS

```
.network-logo {
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px !important;
}

.network-cell > center {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
    border-right: 1px solid gainsboro;
    border-top: 1px solid gainsboro;
    height: 39px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The adjacent cells are formatted differently because they don't contain an image.

For example.

HTML

```
<td>
 <p id="minutes" align="center">300</p>
</td>
```

CSS

```
#minutes, #texts, #data, #infinity {
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-color: gainsboro;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can I make the column 1's border align exactly to the border of column 2,3 + 4?

I know I need to change these to classes also - to view the problem scroll to the bottom of the website and select view mobile version.

http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/samsung-galaxy-j1-white-deals/

> This question is way more complex than the question you highlighted it
>   to be a duplicate of, the rules are different and we are talking about
>   aligning objects formatted as table cells not table cells themselves!

Comment: Great... On it. `:)` And man, your website is dead slow on a 100 mbps connection. Care to check that?

Comment: I need to upgrade the hosting its on shared atm with a product database of about 50,000 lol

Comment: Giving up. You are using `<center>` and other deprecated tags, with `vertical-align` used wrong. Can I suggest an alternate code for the boxes without the tables?

Comment: Yeah course I know center is depreciated I need to change that

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the `id=` with `class=`, as `id` shouldn't be duplicated. Just remove the `<tbody>` structure there and replace with the following:

```css
.row {font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;}
.row > div {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; background: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #ccc; line-height: 40px; padding: 0 10px;}
.row .network-cell {background: #fff; padding: 0;}
.row img {display: inline-block; line-height: 1; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="network-cell">
    <img class="network-logo" src="http://mobilereactor.co.uk//wp-content/themes/wootique-child/images/network-logos/three-logo.png" alt="Three" />
  </div>
  <div class="minutes">100</div>
  <div class="infinity">unltd*</div>
  <div class="data">500MB</div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: Preview]

Comment: I'd prefer not to mess with the table body structure as I have datatables running in the background targeting specific columns and managing the filters, can this be done without the restructure? sorry I didn't know you meant remove td tags

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-collapse: collapse` on each offending element. I believe that would be `<center>` and `<img>`. `border-spacing: 0` may be of use as well. Keep in mind that your metro stylesheet reset the `border-collapse: separate`, so either place the styles in a `<style>` block with `!important`, or use inline, or better yet, assign classes.

Answer (score -1):

With minimal effort:

```
.network-cell > center {
...
...
top: 6px;
...
...
}
```

But use table for alignment isn't so good, in this case better div with display: inline-block, and the tag center is deprecated.

Comment: in firefox there all uneven